# Urban Airship device registration generating a new APID after application data is cleared

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I've noticed an issue with my Android application that receives push notifications through Urban Airship (via C2DM).

The application registers with Urban Airship when it is first installed. When the user launches the app, they are asked to provide a user ID and password to the system the app interfaces with. After successful authentication, this user ID is assigned as the Urban Airship alias for this instance.

The problem occurs when the user clears the application data for the app. The next time the app launches, it re-registers with Urban Airship, but receives a different APID. The user enters their credentials again, and now I have two different APIDs with the same alias referring to the same device. Whenever I send a broadcast message or a message directed at that alias, the app receives the message twice. Obviously, I don't want this happening.

At the same time, it is entirely possible that the user could have the app installed on two different devices (say, a phone and a tablet), in which case I would have the same alias assigned to two different APIDs and that would be okay. My issue is when the two APIDs refer to the same device.

I'm trying to figure out how I can prevent this from happening. I was hoping there might be some kind of intent that gets fired when the user elects to clear the application data, but it seems such an intent doesn't exist.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and were you able to come up with a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the urban air has fixed the issue at their end.Now if multiple device ids are registered under same alias , they just send the message to the last registered one.Although it fixes your issue 
but creates a new another kind of issue as if some user have two devices ids registered under some alias only the last one gets the push notification.But getting multiple notifications  on a single device due to multiple registrations is more prominent and bad use case , hence i guess they must have considered this trade-off.